# ANOVA different p-values on logarithmic and linear scale

Tags: r, anova, inference, lognormal-distribution

I want to compare two groups with one-way anova. I tried to do that using log and linear scale to see if both scales are different one another, and yes the p-values are different.

I am using r for this

```
function(x){
    return(c(y = median(x)*1.075, label = length(x)))
  }
  data<-mtcars
  data$am<-as.factor(data$am)
  data$gear<-as.factor(data$gear)
  data %>% 
    ggplot(aes(y=mpg,x=gear,fill=gear))+
    geom_boxplot()+
    stat_compare_means(method = "anova",hide.ns = T,label="p",label.y =2)+
    scale_y_continuous(trans = "log10")+
    theme(legend.position = "right",
          text = element_text(size = 14, family = "serif"),
          axis.text.x = element_blank())+
    stat_summary(fun.data = give.n, geom = "text", fun.y = median,
                 position = position_dodge(width = 0.75))+
    facet_grid(.~am)
```

and the second boxplot using linear scale by deleting this part `scale_y_continuous(trans = "log10")+`
then the p-value showed different results.
In my data, sometimes the differences were so obvious that changed from not significant into significant after transformed to log scale.

My questions are:

1. How can we decide in what case we should transform to log before doing the test?
2. can we perform anova if the sample in each group was totally different, let say group one has 10 samples but group two has 100 samples. Will the test would fit?

Thank you

Comment: You should not use ggplot2 to conduct ANOVA. The decision for transformations is usually based on model diagnostics and you can't do those if you don't have a separate model object.